# aspnet_regsql.exe creates dbo.aspnet_users but visual 2013 requires dbo.AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-identity

I'm using aspnet_regsql.exe for creating roles and users tables (dbo.aspnet_Roles, dbo.aspnet_Users). Creating roles works fine but when I try to save an user from my visual website application it throws the following error:

Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'

I used the following code so I can decide which is my users table, but it didn't work.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("aspnet_Users", "dbo");
}
```

Here is my web.config

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
    <providers>        
        <clear />
        <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
    <providers>
        <clear />
    </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager defaultProvider="SqlProvider" enabled="true">     
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong in the web.config or using aspnet_regsql.exe (by the way, I'm using the wizard)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that if I used RoleManager to add roles into my application, those would be save in dbo.AspNetRoles and there is no conflict when adding a role to an user.

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
var str = roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("admin"));
```